# Why would fstream.fail() return true or false

Tags: c++

I'm working through some work with some code already provided. There is an if statement that includes 2 fstream.fails(). The code is continually returning true and I'm not sure if it's because of a problem with the provided code or if I am missing something.

I've googled around to try and better understand what could be going on, but due to me being new to C++, I'm finding it hard to find an answer that helps me understand what might be going on.

The provided code where I think might be a problem.

```
bool Navigation::BuildNetwork(const string &fileNamePlaces, const string &fileNameLinks)
{
    fstream finPlaces(fileNamePlaces);
    fstream finLinks(fileNameLinks);
    if (finPlaces.fail() || finLinks.fail()) return false;
    ifstream();

    // Add your code here   
}
```

Where the "Build network" function is called

```
ACW_Wrapper wrapper("log.txt");

    // Build Navigation
    wrapper.startTimer();
    Navigation nav;
    if (nav.BuildNetwork("Places.csv", "Links.csv")) {
        const auto elapsed = wrapper.stopTimer();
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << "BuildNetwork - " << elapsed << " microseconds" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\n*** Error *** BuildNetwork" << std::endl;
    }
```

I would expect it to return false since this is provided code, but I'm unsure if I need to add something that would give me the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [ios::fail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) documentation:

> true if badbit (Read/writing error on I/O operation) and/or failbit (Logical error on i/o operation) are set.

which suggests that at least one of the two files is not opened successfully.

The problem is not in the code, the problem is with your program trying to open files that are not probably found (or it doesn't have permissions to).

Copy the files to the same workspace (folder) with your executable, and try again.